# How can I configure logging to log CXF inbound and outbound restful messages?

Tags: java, spring, apache, web-services, logging

I have created Restful Web Service in that creating log file using log4j  Instead of java.util.logging. but it didn't write for **inbound and outbound** messages to log file.

**below to message logging configuration.**

I created to **META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger** file. then i put below configuration line.

```
org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger
```

Then I created **WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties** configuration file. below to **log4j** configuration

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout


# Direct log messages to a log file

    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\wslog\\log.txt
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**below configuration for Enable to message logging in cxf.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/rest">
             <jaxrs:features>
               <cxf:logging/>
           </jaxrs:features>
           <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                <ref bean="MultiArgs" />
           </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
           </jaxrs:server>
             <bean id="MultiArgs" class="com.multiArgs.MultiArgsImpl" />
    </beans>
```

**I got logging messages for**

```
18:48:55,168  INFO ContextLoader:194 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
18:48:55,200  INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:456 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Nov 17 18:48:55 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
18:48:55,231  INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf.xml]
18:48:55,293  INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
18:48:55,418  INFO DefaultListableBeanFactory:557 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8245e9: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,base,MultiArgs]; root of factory hierarchy
18:48:56,883  INFO ContextLoader:221 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1699 ms
```

**above only i got it. but i want also inbound and outbound messages. anybody help to me...**

Comment: did you get an answer for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logging feature that you've enabled will make use of the class: `org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature`

To enable the printing of the payloads, as part of inbound/outbound , enable the prettyLogging attribute to **true**

Here's the code configuration:

```
<bean id="loggingFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature">
    <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Then refer the bean:

```
 <jaxrs:features>
     <ref bean="loggingFeature"/>
</jaxrs:features>
```

This should log all the RESTFul requests/responses

Comment: Enabling the logging on the Bus, will log all call SOAP / jax-ws calls included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change cxf.xml file as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" 
        xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/core 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
        <cxf:bus>
         <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
         </cxf:features>
        </cxf:bus>

        <jaxrs:server id="base" address="/rest">

               <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
                    <ref bean="MultiArgs" />
               </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
         </jaxrs:server>
           <bean id="MultiArgs" class="com.multiArgs.MultiArgsImpl" />
        </beans>
```